# How do I start a installed tar.xz file that i installed through terminal?

Tags: command-line, tar

I don't know how to do this because i am trying to install Side-quest but its a

> tar.xz

file. Please help me. :(

Comment: For that, you first of all need to add what was inside tar, how you got that, where you have extracted.

Comment: Decompress `$ tar xvf SideQuest-0.10.1.tar.xz` ... and run "sidequest" `$ cd SideQuest-0.10.1/ && ./sidequest`

Answer (score 3):

Just decrompress the `.xz` file.
To do this, you may install `xz-utils` with

```
sudo apt install xz-utils
```

This may not be necessary, but if the following doesn't work, execute it.
Then, decompress it with

```
tar -xvf data.tar.xz
```

After that, execute the decompressed file from the `.xz` file.